# Combinations of Words...Power Set?

Tags: python, c++, powerset

I'm looking to crack a password I forgot. I know all the words possibly used in the password however some may be used or not. Example: HarryMetSally could be the password but I might use a wordlist of "Harry" "Billy" "Sally" and "Met" to combine to crack.

If I have 16 words but 14-16 were probably used, how would I code in C++ or Python to have 16 words (or 20, 25, 30 words) randomly joined together and used 1 at a time or 2-16 together not in the same order even.

Example:

Words: Harry Billy Sally Met

Combination examples:

Harry
Billy
SallyBilly
BillySally
HarryMetSally
HarrySallyMet

I've searched the internet extensively and tried Excel forums as well. Any guidance?

Comment: Certainly! https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Comment: If you use Python, you might be able to use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) or other functions in the same module. If you look towards the bottom of the documentation, they have an example of how you’d calculate a power set using it.

Comment: This seems like a huge number of possible permutations...

Comment: Is this an exercise or a matter of practicality? If you actually forgot your password, I doubt that your first idea is to write a python script to brute force it.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I have locked 35,000 professional photos in a rar file. I know the words that I used to protect it. It is very important I can run a word list against the rar file to unlock it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said random...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

#define NUM_WORDS 3
char* words[NUM_WORDS] = {
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Baz"
};
typedef unsigned long long ULL;

ULL fact(ULL n, ULL lowerLimit = 1)
{
    if (n <= lowerLimit) return 1;
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    // I can try single words all by myself, so start at 2 or more words
    for (int nWords = 2; nWords <= NUM_WORDS; ++nWords)
    {
        // calculate the number of possibilities
        // but since it's random, triple it for good measure
        ULL nIters = fact(NUM_WORDS, NUM_WORDS - nWords) * 3;
        for (ULL iter = 0; iter < nIters; ++iter)
        {
            for (int iterWord = 0; iterWord < nWords; ++iterWord)
            {
                int ix = rand() % NUM_WORDS;
                std::cout << words[ix];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're a smarty :). It runs nicely on a C++ online compiler.